# What is extention .html.arb for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am in a project in which I found a file with the extension .html.arb, in my app/admin folder.
What is the difference between this extension and the .html.erb extension?

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/a/andrewroth_activeadmin-0.3.4.3/Arbre/Builder.html

Comment: ^ the link is now dead. for convenience: https://github.com/activeadmin/arbre

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@levinalex already pointed you in the right direction, but to make it more clear:

`.html.arb` is the view partial designation for [Arbre](https://github.com/gregbell/arbre), just like `.html.erb` is used by ERB and `.html.haml` is used by Haml.

Comment: Would you mind marking your question as having been answered?